# How to default terminal startup?

Tags: command-line, grub2, startup, default

I know that you can show the process of starting up by pressing alt + space during startup how do you have that as default on your computer?  Also i would like to see it on shutdown if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: It says i am not the owner even though i am the owner...any fix?

Comment: You need root permissions. Try `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` from a terminal.

Comment: Or, you know, you could edit it with OpenOffice writer ;)

Comment: @MartinOrda With the wink and your background I suspect you know this, but a newbie may take you literally. It would be dangerous to edit such a critical file as the bootloader config file with a word processor.

Comment: I just find it amusing when people need to have a GUI editor to edit a system configuration file on a Unix derivative system. I wonder what they do if someone presses CTRL+ALT+F1 on their keyboard and there's no longer any GUI? :)